# Wierd NSKeyedArchiver behavior after updating to XCode 9

Tags: ios, swift, nskeyedarchiver, nscoder

I had an app which worked perfect with Xcode 8. Now I'm preparing some minor update and faced with unexpected behavior of `NSKeyedArchiver`. Below the code which worked with no issues before updating to Xcode 9:

```
func saveChecklist(_ checklist : [SingleSection], name: String){
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.allDomainsMask, true)
        let path: AnyObject = paths[0] as AnyObject
        let fileName = "/" + name + ".qad"
        let arrPath = path.appending(fileName)
        NSKeyedArchiver.setClassName("SingleSection", for: SingleSection.self)
        NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(checklist, toFile: arrPath)
    }
```

Now the last line provokes crash with error message:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

I didn't change this part of code at all and I have no ideas what's going on. I believe that root of the problem is in class definition, but once again, everything was good before updating. Below is a class definition:

```
class SingleSection: NSCoder {

    var sectionName: String
    var itemsInSection: [String]
    var isChecked: [Bool]
    var itemsComment: [String]
    var finding: [Int]!
    var images: [[String]]!
    var videos: [[String]]!


    override init() {
        sectionName = ""
        itemsInSection = []
        isChecked = []
        itemsComment = []
        finding = []
        images = []
        videos = []
    }

    init (coder aDecoder: NSCoder!){
        self.sectionName = (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "sectionName") as? String)!
        self.itemsInSection = (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "itemsInSection") as? [String])!
        self.isChecked = (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "isChecked") as? [Bool])!
        self.itemsComment = (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "itemsComment") as? [String])!
        self.finding = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "finding") as? [Int]
        self.images = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "images") as? [[String]]
        self.videos = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "videos") as? [[String]]
    }


    func encodeWithCoder(_ aCoder: NSCoder!){

        aCoder.encode(sectionName, forKey: "sectionName")
        aCoder.encode(itemsInSection, forKey: "itemsInSection")
        aCoder.encode(isChecked, forKey: "isChecked")
        aCoder.encode(itemsComment, forKey: "itemsComment")
        aCoder.encode(finding!, forKey: "finding")
        aCoder.encode(images!, forKey: "images")
        aCoder.encode(videos!, forKey: "videos")
    }

}
```

Main question is what became wrong after updating and how to workaround. Any help appreciated.

UPDATE: The problem's gone when I adopted `NSCoding`. Thanks for the comments

Comment: Why is the class a subclass of `NSCoder` rather than adopting `NSCoding`. The method signatures of `NSCoding` in Swift 3+ are wrong and you are using too many question and exclamation marks. Since you are going to decode **all** properties, it's guaranteed that the values are not `nil` and you can safely unwrap them. But if `images` and `videos` are supposed to be optionals use regular optionals (`?`)

Comment: @vadian, it was done so because of some "historical reasons". I agree that this code should be remade, but this is not an issue. The question is why it worked before and doesn't now.

Comment: I agree with @vadian, it's better to make you class conform to NSCoding rather than be a subclass of NSCoder. And the force unwrapping of the objects can be a problem here. However, in swift 4 there is a new much nice way of serializing obects, something to consider https://medium.com/monitisemea/swift-4s-codable-one-last-battle-for-serialization-30ceb3ccb051

Comment: @AuRis Forced unwrapping is no problem at all if you (the developer) are encoding all values as  non-optionals.

Comment: Problem's gone. I updated my initial question. Thanks for the comments.